How to keep an Rxjs observable live even after errors (ignore errors)
I'm sending some values to an rxjs pipe followed by a subscription. In case of errors, I want to ignore them and continue with the remaining inputs.
of('foo', 'bar', 'error', 'bazz', 'nar', 'error', 'car').subscribe(...)

So I did this:
async function failIfError(item: string) {
  if (item === 'error') throw new Error('HTTP 500'); // Some error we cant control
  return item;
}

of('foo', 'bar', 'error', 'bazz', 'nar', 'error', 'car')
  .pipe(
    concatMap((item) => failIfError(item)),
    catchError((error) => of(null))
  )
  .subscribe((val) => console.log('value:', val));


Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pfdtrr?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.ts
This is the actual output:
value: foo
value: bar
value: null

How can I modify this code so that it ignores the error (with null) and continue with the execution? So that the output looks like:
value: foo
value: bar
value: null
value: bazz
value: nar
value: null
value: car


Yes, when an failIfError occurs error then catchError returns the null and stops the process. So, please use the form operator in the concatMap function.
Please use the below code
of('foo', 'bar', 'error', 'bazz', 'nar', 'error', 'car').pipe(
        concatMap((item) => from(failIfError(item)).pipe(catchError((error) => of(null)))))
      .subscribe((val) => console.log('value:', val));

The from(failIfError(item)) it will return as Observable and you can handle the error with catchError.

The iif operator comes in handy here, it allows you to pipe on it to catch the error and let the outer observable to continue.
of('foo', 'bar', 'error', 'bazz', 'nar', 'error', 'car')
  .pipe(
    concatMap((item) =>
      iif(
        () => item === 'error',
        throwError(() => new Error('HTTP 422')),
        of(item)
      ).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(null);
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((val) => console.log('value:', val));

